# Making a scrictly increasing graph into a sinus rhythm sort of graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Right now I have a graph of this sort:
[image]

But I want to make the above graph into something like this:

[image]

Can anyone guide me how to do this using Matplotlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try plotting the first difference of your time series such as:

```py
# sample data (this is your "before" data):
df = pd.DataFrame({'data you are plotting now': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

# new data to plot:
df['new data'] = df['data you are plotting now'] - df['data you are plotting now'].shift()
```

assuming `data['data you are plotting now']` is your current time series

I should add that generally you should add your code and your input data as well as your expected output data and not images.